# jQuery mouseenter & click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, responsive-design

I can' t find a solution for a RWD problem on my website.

I have one breakpoint (575.98px).
If resolution is above that breakpoint, "mouseenter" event is active to show hidden section:

```
if ($(window).width() > 575.98) {
    $(".name").on("mouseenter", () => {
      $(".description").fadeIn(250);
```

but for resolution below a breakpoint I want to off "mouseenter" event and active "onClick" event.

```
if ($(window).width() <= 575.98) {
  $(".name").on("click", () => {
        $(".description").show();
```

Currently, code is not working below decided breakpoint.

Please give me any hints of solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can check out the px event.

```
$(".name").on("mouseenter", function() {
 if ($(window).width() > 575.98){
  $(".description").fadeIn(250);
 }
});


$(".name").on("click", function() {
 if ($(window).width() <= 575.98){
  $(".description").show();
 }
});
```

Comment: Thnx a lot @Cem PEHLIVAN. I checked out yours solution but finally I decided to use jQuery mobile API, so I do not need to use special jquery events for different resolutions. Bye.